# Regular expression to match line separated size strings

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, regex

I am writing a reular expression to validate input string, which is a line separated list of sizes ([width]x[height]).

Valid input example:

```
300x200
50x80


100x100
```

The regular expression I initially came up with is (https://regex101.com/r/H9JDjA/1):

```
^(\d+x\d+[\r\n|\r|\n]*)+$
```

This regular expression matches my input but also matches this invalid input (size can't be 100x100x200):

```
300x200
50x80
100x100x200
```

Adding a word boundary at the end seems to have fixed this issue:

```
^(\d+x\d+[\r\n|\r|\n]*\b)+$
```

My questions:

1. Why does the initial regular expression without the word boundary fail? It looks like I am matching one or more instances of a \d+(number), followed by character 'x', followed by a \d+(number), followed by one or more new lines from various operating systems.
2. How to validate input having multiple training new line characters in this input? The following doesn't work for some kind of inputs like this:

   500x500\n100x100\n\n\n384384

   ^(\d+x\d+[\r\n|\r|\n]*\b)+|[\r\n|\r|\n]*$

Comment: Is matching on a per-line-basis an option?

Comment: @Jan Yes splitting by new line and matching each line is an option, but I am trying to figure out why that initial regex matches 1x1x1

Comment: @dev_musings Actually it doesn't match 1x1x1, you can test it out by your own link. But since you're matching multiple lines - last line is included partially in the match and it is correct. You may need php equivalent of `preg_match_all` or need to split lines and match them separately.

Comment: Is this happening in js or php?  Your pattern link suggests php.  Are you extracting the valid values or just validating the entire multi-line text?

Comment: It's not language specific, I am just testing the regex. I am validating the entire multi line text.

Comment: Can you fully explain (and offer an all encompassing sample input) the variability of the data?  Might it start and end with line returns?  Might the dimensions be single-digit? Quadruple-digit? Etc?  I understand from your question that the `x` is optional.  Please clarify these critical points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the problem with this target `100x100x200`

For now, forget about the anchors in the regex.

The minimum regex is `\d+x\d+` since it only has to be satisfied once
for a match to take place.

The maximum is something like this `\d+x\d+ (?: (?:\r?\n | \r)* \d+x\d+ )*`

Since `\r?\n|\r` is optional, it can be reduced to this `\d+x\d+ (?: \d+x\d+ )*`

The result, when you applied to the target string is:

`100x100`x200 matches.

But, since you've *anchored* the regex `^$`, it is forced to break up
the middle 100 to make it match.

`100x10` from *\d+x\d+*
`0x200` from *(?: \d+x\d+ )**

So, that is why the first regex seemingly matches `100x100x200`.

To avoid all of that, just require a line break between them, and
make the trailing linebreaks optional (if you need to validate the whole
string, otherwise leave it and the end anchor off).

`^\d+x\d+(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)+\d+x\d+)*(?:\r?\n|\r)*$`

A better view of it

```
 ^ 
 \d+ x \d+ 
 (?:
      (?: \r? \n | \r )+
      \d+ x \d+ 
 )*
 (?: \r? \n | \r )*
 $
```

Comment: Some people wouldn't know a good answer if it bit them.  It would be simpler for the OP to use `\v` right?  `^(\d+x\d+\b\v*)+$`  (... or even `\s` considering the sample input)

Comment: @mickmackusa - Regarding `\v`: When it comes to whitespace, I never use a construct that has a dual meaning inside/outside character classes. For this reason, _`\v`_ is a sin. Inside a class `[\v]` it is a vertical tab (U+0B), outside it is `[\x0A-\x0D\x85\x{2028}\x{2029}]`, where `[^\V]` is a vertical whitespace. For this reason, Java has steered clear, and Perl (with 5.18) just added vt to it's _minimal_ whitespace class `[ \f\n\r\t\v]` To me, `\R` is more correct, since it coerces `\r\n` as a single depending on platform. In this case, `\b` is a good choice to enforce `\d` separation.

Comment: @mickmackusa - However, sticking a `\b` in here `^(\d+x\d+\b\v*)+$` makes one have to think a bit as to what it is doing, where as `^\d+x\d+(?:\R+\d+x\d+)*\R*$` _unrolls_ the option pretty clearly. Using the `\b` however, makes the first regex about 1 tenth of %1 faster. This is because the `\b` construct is implemented as primitive in C,  where as `\R` requires more work in it's implementation.

Comment: @sln Thanks for the detailed analysis. Understood the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial regular expression "fails" because of the `+`:

```
^(\d+x\d+[\r\n|\r|\n]*)+$
-----------------------^ here
```

Your parenthesis pattern (`\d+x\d+[\r\n|\r|\n]*`) says *match one or more number followed by an "x" followed by one or more number followed by zero or more newlines*. The `+` after that says *match one or more of the entire parenthesis pattern*, which means that for an input like `100x200x300` your pattern matches `100x200` and then `200x300`, so it looks like it matches the entire line.

If you're simply trying to extract dimensions from a newline-separated string, I would use the following regular expression with a multiline flag:

```
^(\d+x\d+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/H9JDjA/2

Side note: In your expression, `[\r\n|\r|\n]` is actually saying *match any one instance of `\r`, `\n`, `|`, `\r`, `|`, or `\n`* (i.e. it's quite redundant, and you probably aren't meaning to match `|`). If you want to match a sequential set of any combination of `\r` or `\n`, you can simply use `[\r\n]+`.

Comment: That makes sense now. Also the side note about matching new lines was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiline modifier, which should make life easier:

```
var input = "\n\
300x200x400\n\
50x80\n\
\n\
\n\
300x200\n\
50x80\n\
100x100x200x100\n";

var allSizes = input.match(/^\d+x\d+/gm); // multiline modifier assumes each line has start and end
for (var size in allSizes)
    console.log(allSizes[size]);
```

Prints:

```
300x200
50x80
300x200
50x80
100x100
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex out

`^[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}|[(\r\n|\r|\n)]+$`

It'll match these inputs.

`1x1`
`10x10`
`100x100`
`2000x2938`
`\n`
`\r`
`\r\n`
 but not this `100x100x200`